# Keyboard not showing up when EditText is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I've created a method that is called when my EditText is clicked (or touched, to be specific), which simply takes the current time and displays it exactly as it has been passed by `System.currentTimeMillis()` in a TextView below. The method is this one:

```
public void captureTime(View view) {
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String currentTimeStr = currentTime+ "";
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(currentTimeStr);
}
```

To do that, I've had to add the code below in the `onCreate` method. It uses `setOnTouchListener` instead of `setOnClickListener` since otherwise the `captureTime` method wasn't always called. Now, this method does what I wanted, but now when I click or touch the EditText, although it does this as required, the keyboard doesn't show up anymore. I have looked into other questions in which the keyboard doesn't show up either but they're not related to my case, although I have tried them. So, what is that is making the keyboard not show up and how can I fix this?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        add_time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        add_time.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    captureTime(add_time);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing return true (in the if block). In this case, the "captureTime" method will work and the keyboard will open.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But what's the explanation on why this line blocks the keyboard being shown?